# How to incorporate filling in saved values on autocomplete selects

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete of 2 selects.  The first one you make a choice and it populates the second one based on that choice. 
My is this, I can save the record on my submit data but how do I get the saved values for that record and make those values the selected ones.  Here is my code for the autocomplete part.

Here is the html for the 2 fields.

```
<div>
   <label for="incimechtype">Incident Mechanism Type</label>
   <select class="ehselect" name="incimechtype" id="incimechtype">
      <option></option>
      <option value="Mechanism">Mechanism</option>
      <option value="Object">Object</option>
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
   </select> 
   <label for="injmechid">Incident Mechanism</label>
   <select id="injmechid" name="injmechid">
   </select> 
</div>
```

here is the ajax jquery script

```
$(function(){
$("#incimechtype").change(function(){        

    var dropdown = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
         url:"getinjuryjson.php",

         dataType: "json"  
    }).done( function(data){

         $("#injmechid").find("option").remove();
         if(dropdown !== ""){
            $("#injmechid").append($('<option/>'));
         }
         switch(dropdown){
                case "Mechanism":

                    $.each(data, function(key,value){
                        if(value.injmech==='Mechanism'){
                            $("#injmechid").append($('<option/>',{
                            value: value.injmechid,
                            text: value.injmechdescrip
                            }));
                            }
                    });
                    break;
                case "Other":

                    $.each(data, function(key,value){
                        if(value.injmech==='Other'){
                            $("#injmechid").append($('<option/>',{
                            value: value.injmechid,
                            text: value.injmechdescrip
                            }));
                            }
                    });
                    break;
                case "Object":

                    $.each(data, function(key,value){
                        if(value.injmech==='Object'){
                            $("#injmechid").append($('<option/>',{
                            value: value.injmechid,
                            text: value.injmechdescrip
                            }));
                            }
                    });
                    break;
                }

    }
    )
}
) 
}
);
```

And here is the php code.

```
<?php

include('common.php');
if(!($_SESSION['incident']['mechenisms'])){
   $query = "select injmechid,RTRIM(injmechdescrip)injmechdescrip,RTRIM(injmech)injmech  from        hrs.injurymech";
   $result = sqlsrv_query($link,$query,array(),array( "Scrollable" => 'static' )) or die('Cannot get injury mechanism list');
   while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
      $_SESSION['incident']['mechenisms'][] =$row;   
   }
}

echo json_encode($_SESSION['incident']['mechenisms']);
```

Now how in the world do I incorpate the stored record data to select the right choices in the form when I go to edit a saved form.

I am thinking I connect a variable to the ajax call and then query the database for the 2 field values and then somehow have those values selected if they exist.

I figured it out.  I did not do it through the ajax. I did it using php on the page load.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using php to populate the answers.  I left the dynamic ajax in place if the answer was to change.